# Typescript and Durandal.JS and exports

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, durandal, durandal-2.0

What is defining the exports module in the following snippet?

```
define(["require", "exports", 'durandal/app', 'durandal/http'], function(require, exports, __app__, __http__) {
.
.
.
}
```

I checked out [this](https://github.com/Svakinn/TypeTowel) example, opened the solution and couldn't figure out whatever is defining the "exports" module. Is that just native to RequireJS now, or is there an external reference that I'm still missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ass soon as you `import` anything in typescript and compile with `amd` you get a `define` with `require` and `exports`.

`exports` is requireJS handle for anything you want to export from this module. e.g.

```
export var foo = 123;
```

will generate

```
exports.foo = 123;
```

Which is utilized by requirejs import on the other end.